# Android - Views dynamically created, deleting them ruins layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have an arraylist, for every item in that list, output item with a button next to it in order to delete the item from the list.

```
ArrayList<String> alString = new ArrayList();  
//ArrayList gets filled with data items
RelativeLayout Container = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
int Tracker = 500000000;

for (String item:alString){
        final TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText(item);
        textView.setId(Tracker);
        //positioning
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textViewParams = new 
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


        textViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,Tracker - 2);
        textViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);

        textView.setLayoutParams(textViewParams);

        //Create button to remove ingredient
        final Button Xbutton = new Button(this);
        Xbutton.setText("X");
        Xbutton.setId(Tracker + 1);
        //positioning
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams XbuttonParams = new 
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        XbuttonParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, 
        textView.getId());
        XbuttonParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM,  
        textView.getId());
        XbuttonParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

        Xbutton.setLayoutParams(XbuttonParams);

        //When button is clicked, remove the item
        Xbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                alString.remove(item);
                Container.removeView(textView);
                Container.removeView(Xbutton);
            }
        });

        Container.addView(textView);
        Container.addView(Xbutton);

        Tracker = Tracker + 2;
    }  
}
```

The issue is, say there are 10 items and I delete the 5th and 7th item with the Xbuttons, a lot of the items start to overlap. All the views end up just sitting on top of each other. This doesn't happen if I delete them one by one from top to bottom or bottom to top. However, as soon as I delete an item in the middle of the list, they all start to overlap with each other. I know this is because
Tracker - 2 from textViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, Tracker - 2) doesn't exist anymore. However, I need that line of code so they go in order. What do I do to stop the TextViews overlapping?

Answer (score 1):

Try using a ListView with a custom list adapter instead of adding views manually.

1. In your activity:

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
ListAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, dataItems);  //list of items to be added
adapter.setCustomButtonListner(MainActivity.this);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

2. Create a custom list adapter(CustomAdapter) that extends ArrayAdapter
3. Create a layout for every list items and initialize an OnClickListener for the delete button (make sure you set the tag for the button in the getView method of the adapter)
4. Everytime an item is deleted, call notifyDataSetChanged() to refresh the list.